# Build App on Android Pie Device fails in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-9.0-pie

Hello I just updated my Xiaomi Mi A1 to Android Pie.
Now I just started developing a new blank hello world app. But if I want to test it on my device the build process fails. 
The Error is:

```
Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package: de.philow.simpleplayer
at com.android.server.pm.Settings.isOrphaned(Settings.java:4288)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.isOrphaned(PackageManagerService.java:21138)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.deletePackageVersioned(PackageManagerService.java:17949)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.uninstall(PackageInstallerService.java:737)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runUninstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1486)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:193)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21371)
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:634)
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:532)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2796)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3911)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
Error while Installing APKs
```

Thank you for tipps

Comment: I have same issue on Xiaomi Mi A1 to Android Pie. Did you find any solution to it ?

Comment: I've just waited sometime and tried it after a week again and it worked I don't know why. Which Version of Android Studio do you use?